# VPS eating up too much memory

Tags: mysql, memory, vps, cherokee

I have installed CentOS 5.5 minimal on my VPS.
Then I installed mysql (yum mysql mysql-server) and started as a service (service mysqld start)
After that I installed PHP (yum install php).
And finally I installed Cherokee and ProFTPD. (service cherokee start) (service proftpd start).
However, it is eating about 360MB of memory! I think it should consume much less as I don't even have a website running yet.
I've been reading about optimizing the server so that it would consume less memory, however I'm quite new to VPS and even though I modified some config files, it is still eating that much memory.
Memory usage (top):

> Mem:    508716k total,   393896k used,   114820k free,    43456k buffers
>
> Swap:   524280k total,        0k used,   524280k free,   282408k cached

This is the process list (ps aux):

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

root         1  0.0  0.1  10356   672 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 init [3]

root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kthreadd]

root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [migration/0]

root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]

root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [watchdog/0]

root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [migration/1]

root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]

root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [watchdog/1]

root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [migration/2]

root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]

root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [watchdog/2]

root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [migration/3]

root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]

root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [watchdog/3]

root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [events/0]

root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [events/1]

root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [events/2]

root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [events/3]

root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [khelper]

root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [async/mgr]

root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [xenwatch]

root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [xenbus]

root        80  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [sync_supers]

root        82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [bdi-default]

root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kblockd/0]

root        84  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kblockd/1]

root        85  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kblockd/2]

root        86  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kblockd/3]

root        94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kseriod]

root       148  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [khungtaskd]

root       149  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kswapd0]

root       150  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [aio/0]

root       151  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [aio/1]

root       152  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [aio/2]

root       153  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [aio/3]

root       154  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [crypto/0]

root       155  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [crypto/1]

root       156  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [crypto/2]

root       157  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [crypto/3]

root       368  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [khvcd]

root       444  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kpsmoused]

root       454  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ksuspend_usbd]

root       455  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [khubd]

root       464  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ata/0]

root       465  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ata/1]

root       466  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ata/2]

root       467  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ata/3]

root       468  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ata_aux]

root       471  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kstriped]

root       477  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [ksnapd]

root       505  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kjournald]

root       558  0.0  0.1  12612   752 ?        S<s  Sep01   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d

root      1412  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kmpathd/0]

root      1413  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kmpathd/1]

root      1414  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kmpathd/2]

root      1415  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kmpathd/3]

root      1416  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kmpath_handle]

root      1708  0.0  0.1   5916   664 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 syslogd -m 0

root      1711  0.0  0.0   3812   432 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 klogd -x

root      1722  0.0  0.2  62632  1216 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd

root      1730  0.0  0.2  19712  1148 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 crond

root      1799  0.0  0.2  10904  1320 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 /bin/sh

root      1804  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 [kauditd]

root      1993  0.0  0.2  10768  1256 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --l

mysql     2043  0.0  4.9 164128 25204 ?        Sl   Sep01   0:10 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run

root      2161  0.0  0.1  23836   692 ?        Ssl  Sep01   0:00 /usr/sbin/cherokee --config=/etc/cherokee/cherokee.conf -d pidfile /var/run/cherokee.pid

nobody    2220  0.0  0.3  49468  1572 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)

root      2325  0.0  0.6 273476  3340 ?        Sl   Sep01   0:04 /usr/sbin/cherokee-worker --config=/etc/cherokee/cherokee.conf  pidfile /var/run/cherokee.pi

root      2345  0.0  1.1  78316  5820 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:47990

root      2346  0.0  0.7  78664  3732 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:47990

root      2347  0.0  0.7  78600  3600 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:47990

root      2348  0.0  0.7  78600  3604 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:47990

root      2349  0.0  0.7  78664  3692 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:47990

root      2350  0.0  0.7  78664  3664 ?        S    Sep01   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:47990

root     12288  0.0  0.6  90164  3392 ?        Ss   07:35   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0

root     12290  0.0  0.2  10900  1448 pts/0    Ss   07:35   0:00 -bash

root     12323  0.0  0.1  10464   900 pts/0    R+   07:53   0:00 ps aux
```

Can you help me to know what to configure to eat less memory?

Answer (score 1):

You are ok. See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about caching. In 7 minutes I'll accept your answer.
The real RAM I have free is 430MB, and I'm only using 66MB

Comment: Really? 114820k free, 43456k buffers - that still only gives around 160MB free

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, drop your prefork values inside /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. I've got a 256MB slice running similar and I'm using the values below. Also go through that file and comment out all the LoadModules and do `/etc/init.d/httpd configtest` and put any back in that it complains about. You can also remove PHP extensions to help a bit.

My 256MB slice is currently using the following, running MySQL and Apache with the following memory:
`total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:           256        240         15          0         46         90

-/+ buffers/cache:        103        152

Swap:          511         11        500`

My prefork is as low as:
`<IfModule prefork.c>

StartServers       2

MinSpareServers    3

MaxSpareServers    8

ServerLimit      100

MaxClients       100

MaxRequestsPerChild  200

</IfModule>`
My my.cnf is:
`[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer = 4M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 25
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 64K
skip-bdb
skip-innodb
query_cache_limit = 256K
query_cache_size = 4M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout`

Obviously you will need to amend this for anything you need.